# Voltando para o topo da tela ao escrever no campo

Tags: android, listview

Estou com o seguinte erro: Tenho uma lista e um campo, toda vez que eu edito qualquer edit text da lista, ele perde o foco e vai para o topo da tela, observe o gif que a cada letra da palavra "teste" o edittext perde e ganha foco, só que o primeiro não dá problema pq ja está no topo da lista, agora os outros que estão abaixo do primeiro dão...
[image: Erro quando escrevo]

Código da Activity

```
public class CategoriaListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private Categoria categoria = new Categoria();
private ListView listView;
Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence titles[] = {"Receita", "Despesa"};
int numTabs = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categoria_list);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Window window = getWindow();
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), titles, numTabs);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_black));
    }

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    tabs.setViewPager(pager);


    //refreshLista();


}
public void addCategoriaDespesa(View view) {

    final EditText etCatDes = (EditText)
            findViewById(R.id.etCateg);

    ImageButton btCatDes = (ImageButton)
            findViewById(R.id.btAdd);


    if(etCatDes.getText().toString().length() == 0){
        etCatDes.setError("Campo obrigatório");
        return;
    }

    categoria.setNome(etCatDes.getText().toString());
    categoria.setDespesa(1);

    CategoriaDAO categoriaDAO = new CategoriaDAO(this);
    categoriaDAO.inserir(categoria);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Categoria adicionada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    etCatDes.setText("");

    refreshLista(1);
}

public void addCategoriaReceita(View view) {

    final EditText etCatRec = (EditText)
            findViewById(R.id.etCategR);

    ImageButton btCatRec = (ImageButton)
            findViewById(R.id.btAdd);

    if (etCatRec.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        etCatRec.setError("Campo obrigatório");
        return;
    }

    categoria.setNome(etCatRec.getText().toString());
    categoria.setDespesa(0);


    CategoriaDAO categoriaDAO = new CategoriaDAO(this);
    categoriaDAO.inserir(categoria);



    Toast.makeText(this, "Categoria adicionada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    refreshLista(0);
    etCatRec.setText("");
}


public void refreshLista(int despesa) {
    CategoriaDAO categoria = new CategoriaDAO(this);
    List<Categoria> list = categoria.getLista(despesa);
    ListView listView;
    if (despesa == 1) {
        listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listaDes);
    }else {
        listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    }
    CategoriaAdapter catAd = new CategoriaAdapter(this, list, listView);
    listView.setAdapter(catAd);
}

/*   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_categoria_list, menu);
    return true;
}*/

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**Editado**.

Xml da Activity

```
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<com.prjctt.allan.newfinance.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment e xml do Fragment que trata essa parte do gif

```
public class CategoriaReceita extends Fragment {
    Categoria categoria;
    EditText etCat;
    ImageButton addCat;

public CategoriaReceita() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categoria_receita, container, false);

    addCat = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btAddR);
    etCat = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etCategR);

    refreshLista(v);
    return v;


}
public void refreshLista(View layout) {
    CategoriaDAO categoria = new CategoriaDAO(this.getActivity());
    List<Categoria> list = categoria.getLista(0);
    ListView listView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    CategoriaAdapter catAd = new CategoriaAdapter(this.getActivity(), list, listView);
    listView.setAdapter(catAd);
}



}


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.prjctt.allan.newfinance.CategoriaReceita">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/some_card_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="#cccccc">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etCategR"
            android:hint="Adicione uma categoria"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_newc"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Adicionar"
            android:id="@+id/btAddR"
            android:onClick="addCategoriaReceita"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/some_card_view1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="#cccccc">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Adapter e xml relacionados a lista de categorias

```
public class CategoriaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
List<Categoria> lista;
private ListView listView;
private SubCategoria subcategoria = new SubCategoria();
private TextView lvPai;

public CategoriaAdapter(Context context, List<Categoria> lista, ListView listView) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lista = lista;
    this.listView = listView;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final int auxPosition = position;

    final Categoria categoria = new Categoria();


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    final CardView layout = (CardView)
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.categoria_row, null);

    final TextView categ = (TextView)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.tvCat);
    categ.setText(lista.get(position).getNome());

    final EditText etsubcat = (EditText)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.etSubCat);

    final ImageButton btaddsub = (ImageButton)
            layout.findViewById(R.id.btAddSubCat);



    etsubcat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            etsubcat.requestFocus();
        }
    });

    btaddsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Categoria cat = (Categoria) getItem(position);

            subcategoria.setNome(etsubcat.getText().toString());
            subcategoria.setIdCategoria(cat.getId());


            SubCategoriaDAO subCategoriaDAO = new SubCategoriaDAO(context);

            if(etsubcat.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                etsubcat.setError("Campo obrigatório");
            }else {
                subCategoriaDAO.inserir(subcategoria);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Subcategoria adicionada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                etsubcat.setText("");

                lvPai = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvCat);
                List<SubCategoria> list = subCategoriaDAO.getLista(lvPai.getText().toString());
                ListView listView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                /*ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =listView.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = list.size() * 42;
                listView.setLayoutParams(params);
                listView.requestLayout();*/
                listView.setAdapter(new SubCategoriaAdapter(context, list, listView));
            }
        }
    });


    listView.setDivider(null);


    lvPai = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvCat);
    SubCategoriaDAO subcategoria = new SubCategoriaDAO(context);
    List<SubCategoria> list = subcategoria.getLista(lvPai.getText().toString());
    ListView listView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(new SubCategoriaAdapter(context, list, listView));


    return layout;
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/some_card_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:background="#cccccc">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/tvCat" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etSubCat"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btAddSubCat"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvCat"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvCat"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btAddSubCat"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btAddSubCat"
    android:hint="Adicionar subcategoria"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:contentDescription="Adicionar subcategoria"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_newc"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btAddSubCat"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvCat"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:focusable="false"/>


<com.prjctt.allan.newfinance.ExpandedListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btAddSubCat"/>
```

Comment: Seu primeiro **EditText** está com autofoco?

Comment: Poste o código da sua **Activity**.

Comment: Editado @IsraelSousa

Comment: Poste o **XML** da **Activity** também.

Comment: @IsraelSousa Editado

Comment: Não estou conseguindo entender o seu **XML**, onde está o código que contem os dois **EditText**, **subcategoria**, etc.?

Comment: está no adapter da lista, editando @IsraelSousa

Comment: Adapter incluido @IsraelSousa

Comment: Tente remover o **android:focusable="false"** ou mude para **true** e vê o que acontece.

Comment: Do ImageButton? Tem a ver será? @IsraelSousa

Comment: Tem que tentar. Seu código está um pouco confuso, o problema está no momento em que você da um foco para o EdiText **Adicionar subcategoria**.

Comment: Comentei aquela parte, ainda continua o erro... @IsraelSousa

Comment: Na verdade @IsraelSousa o erro é o seguinte, toda vez que eu edito qualquer edit text da lista, ele perde o foco e vai para o topo da tela, observe o gif que a cada letra da palavra "teste" o edittext perde e ganha foco, só que o primeiro não dá problema pq ja está no topo da lista..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui, após uma pesquisa eu descobri o atributo `descendantFocusability`, e fui testando os valores até achar o valor `afterDescendants`.

A ListView ficou assim no xml, isso resolveu meu problema:

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"/>
```

Agradeço aos comentários.